# Symfony send array for action

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, symfony

I have template where I have array for entity developers and I need send this array for action, how can do this
this action

```
{% for developer in developers %}
{{ developer.id }}
{% endfor %}
<a href="{{ path('admin_project_send_email', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">send</a>
```

how send array developers for this action admin_project_send_email

```
 /**
 * Send email for Developers.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/send", name="admin_project_send_email")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @Template()
 * @ParamConverter("entity", class="ArtelProfileBundle:Project")
 */
public function sendAction($entity, Request $request)
{
    $value = $request->getSession()->get('developer');
    return array(
        'developers' => $value,
    );
}
```

I try set in session but if get session variable I have last developer - not array. How can do this with not ajax??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to make a form with a collection type which post an array of entity id's. See the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

And with sessions it could work too. First you have to create an array of id's (and not whole objects)

```
$ids = array();

foreach($developers as $developer)
{
    $ids[] = $developer->getId();
}

$request->getSession()->set('ids', $ids);
```

Comment: cool, 
        if (is_array($developers)) {
            $array_dev = [];
            foreach ($developers as $session_developer) {

                array_push($array_dev, $session_developer);
            }
            $request->getSession()->set('developer', $array_dev);
        }